# How many data points I have to gather to get a statistically significant measurement?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, p-value, missing-data, validation

I'm trying to decide between two methods for interpolation. I validate them on known data. Thus, basically I'm getting two errors with their standard deviations. One greater than the other. How many checks I should run to be sure that the finding is statistically significant? And how do I calculate the p value for it?

EDIT: I'm trying to fill 1h gaps in my time-series data (weather and  power plant demand)

Comment: You don't need to decide whether either interpolation offers "significant" improvement. Indeed it is difficult to see what the appropriate test would be given some dependence structure in your data that makes interpolation sensible at all. You just need to decide which is the better method and if it is better enough than doing nothing to use You need more than SD of errors; you need also mean errors and whether either method can be spectacularly wrong on occasion. It's possible that your greatest problem would be the risk of really large errors. So, two distributions of errors.

Comment: There is no context here but for simplicity I guess interpolation of time series or something loosely similar. Working out the circumstances in which you get the biggest errors might guide choice of method. E.g. spline methods often look good, but they can overshoot..

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NickCox. I actually encountered the overshoots with spline method. Thus, I agree that it might be a problem. However, I don't understand what do you mean by "So, two distributions of errors"?

Comment: You have two distributions of errors, real$_{ij} - $ inter$_{ij}$ for time $i$ and method $j$. PCHIP https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html is spline-like but doesn't overshoot.

Comment: Great thanks @NickCox. I would be very grateful if you just elaborated on an extra simple question. Let's say I have 3000 hours of continuous (no gaps) data. How many checks would you run on it to be sure that one of the methods is doing better than the other?

Comment: I can't that answer that easily. As it happens I have a similar project in mind in which I test various methods by randomly deleting known values and seeing how well they can be interpolated. The empty answer is to test on the kinds of data with the range of behaviour you expect, including as it were rough and smooth, trend-free and trend-dominated.